# Axial shortening of a torsion rod loaded with pure torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

If you have a torsion rod and stress it with pure torsion you expect an axial shortening, too. If you have a lateral contraction property in your material (e.g. steel)

I anyhow cannot calculate the axial deformation caused by torsion e.g.

```
mu=0.3 % Poisson coefficient
sigma=0.1 %Radial strain in rad
l_0=10 %Inertial length of rod
E=210000 %Young's modulus
```

so what I want to calculate is

```
Delta_l=? %Axial displacement
```

According to St. Venant you won't have an axial displacement. But if you take the volume effects into account you will have...

Answer (score 2):

Let us see. The deformation in general can be seen as the superposition of bulk deformation (hydrostatic) plus shear deformation. In your case you only have the shear deformation which means volume is preserved.

So you need to find is the length of an outer fiber as it twists around along the final length of the rod $\ell$. The total twist is given by $\Theta = \frac{T \ell_0}{G\,J_T}$ which I assume you know how to calculate.

The helix has coordinates

$$\vec{r}(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} R \cos\theta  & R \sin \theta & h \theta \end{pmatrix}$$

where $R$ is the radius and $h = \frac{\rm \ell}{\rm \Theta}$ the pitch of the helix. Note that the pitch decreases as the length shrinks. The length of the fiber is equal to the original length $\ell_0$ with:

$$ \ell_{0}=\int\,{\rm d}s=\int\,|{\rm d}\vec{r}|=\int_{0}^{\Theta}\sqrt{R^{2}+h^{2}}\;{\rm d}\theta\\=\Theta\sqrt{R^{2}+h^{2}}=\Theta\sqrt{R^{2}+\left(\frac{\ell}{\Theta}\right)^{2}}   $$

which yields the final length $\ell$ by

$$ \frac{ \ell_0}{ \Theta} = \sqrt{R^2 + \left(\frac{\ell}{\Theta}\right)^2} $$

$$ \boxed{ \ell = \sqrt{ \ell_0^2 - R^2 \Theta^2 } }$$

Comment: Thank you ja72! The solution you provided based on a helix spring and not on a conventional torsion rod. You mean it can be applied simply to a rod?

Comment: @Caniko No ja72 is modelling a solid rod. The rod is thought of as being made up of fibres, which, as a first approximation, do not lengthen because there is only shear, no tension (which would arise with things like bending moment).

Comment: @Caniko it is a solid rod as explained, but twisted. Think of it as a bundle of pasta noodles and twist it. It will create a helix.

Comment: Now that I think about it this is amount of shortening of the outer fibers. The overall shortening might be less, as you would have to average over the entire solid.